# Generate Signed URL for Azure Blob Storage using Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to create signed URLs for a file in Azure Blob using Java SDK.
Here is the snippet that is used -

```
String container = "test";
String path = "hello/world.json";
long expiry = 2000;
SharedKeyCredentials creds = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);

BlobSASPermission blobSASPermission = new BlobSASPermission().withRead(true).withCreate(true).withWrite(true);

AccountSASSignatureValues signatureValues = new AccountSASSignatureValues()
        .withResourceTypes(new AccountSASResourceType().withService(true).withContainer(true).withObject(true).toString())
        .withServices(new AccountSASService().withBlob(true).toString())
        .withPermissions(blobSASPermission.toString())
        .withProtocol(SASProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY)
        .withStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now())
        .withExpiryTime(OffsetDateTime.now().plusSeconds(expiry));


URL blobURL = new BlobURLParts()
        .withScheme("https://")
        .withHost(accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net")
        .withContainerName(container)
        .withBlobName(path)
        .withSasQueryParameters(signatureValues.generateSASQueryParameters(creds))
        .toURL();
```

When I send out a GET/PUT/POST curl request on the `blobURL` I get the following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:c8192b20-c01e-0056-23ca-5e06e8000000
Time:2019-08-30T00:30:03.2903571Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was playmentdiag
rcw
b
sco
2019-08-30T00:27:42Z
2019-08-30T01:01:02Z

https
2018-03-28
</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to upload files with the same credentials and it worked perfectly fine. Java SDK- `com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage-blob:10.1.0`

Comment: Can you share the SAS token? Just obfuscate the `sig` portion of the SAS token.

Comment: You mean this - `?sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&spr=https&st=2019-08-30T00%3A27%3A42Z&se=2019-08-30T01%3A01%3A02Z&sp=rcw&sig=XXX`

Comment: Yep, that’s it. Can you tell me what version of SDK you’re using?

Comment: It is already mentioned in the post. Mentioning it again - `com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage-blob:10.1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is something conflicts with blob SAS permission create and write, disable either of them , your code works well on my side with the similar env as you:

```
BlobSASPermission blobSASPermission = new BlobSASPermission().withRead(true).withCreate(false).withWrite(true);
```

or

```
BlobSASPermission blobSASPermission = new BlobSASPermission().withRead(true).withCreate(true).withWrite(false);
```

Btw, this is the only doc I can find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#constructing-the-account-sas-uri , as you can see under "SignedPermission" section indicated that the create permission can not overwrite existing blobs or files , but write permission is used for writing to existing objs , I think this is the conflict here .

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Please update the answer if you know a source. I need to wait for 6 hours to reward the bounty. Thanks for the answer.